# How do I retun two objects in the same function?

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, oop

I have a function that returns an object:

```
public PathDetailsMessage GetDataFromDatabase()
{
    PathDetailsMessage pathDetailsMessage = new PathDetailsMessage();
    pathDetailsMessage.MessageTypeVersion = "5.3";

    PlannedJourneyLocation plannedJourneyLocation = new PlannedJourneyLocation();
    plannedJourneyLocation.CountryCodeISO.Value = "RO";

    return pathDetailsMessage;
}
```

I have two public partial classes: `PathDetailsMessage` and `PlannedJourneyLocation`.

To test, I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PathDetailsBLL train = new PathDetailsBLL();
    PathDetailsMessage pdm = train.GetDataFromDatabase();
}
```

Using Console.Write(), I can see the value of `MessageTypeVersion` but I can't see the value from object `plannedJourneyLocation`.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You can create an additional class that has `PathDetailsMessage` and `PlannedJourneyLocation` as properties.

Comment: Also if it is a class object you can put in the parameter list.  Any changes to a class object in the parameter list also get changed in the parent method.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `tuple` depending on your version of `C#` (`7.0`):

```
public (PathDetailsMessage Message,PlannedJourneyLocation Location) GetDataFromDatabase()
{
    PathDetailsMessage pathDetailsMessage = new PathDetailsMessage();
    pathDetailsMessage.MessageTypeVersion = "5.3";

    PlannedJourneyLocation plannedJourneyLocation = new PlannedJourneyLocation();
    plannedJourneyLocation.CountryCodeISO.Value = "RO";

    return (pathDetailsMessage, plannedJourneyLocation);
}
```

You can then call this from you `Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = GetDataFromDatabase();
    PathDetailsMessage pdm = data.Message;
    plannedJourneyLocation journey = data.Location;
}
```

Comment: note that you can also use syntax `var (message, location) = GetDataFromDatabase()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a object that includes that 2 objects mentioned.

```
    public class MyObject
{
   public PathDetailsMessage PathDetailsMessage {get;set;}
   public PlannedJourneyLocation PlannedJourneyLocation {get; set;}
}
```

Then you have to modify the method :

```
public MyObject GetDataFromDatabase()
{    
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    myObject.PathDetailsMessage = = new PathDetailsMessage();
    myObject.PathDetailsMessage.MessageTypeVersion = "5.3";

    myObject.PlannedJourneyLocation = new PlannedJourneyLocation();
    myObject.PlannedJourneyLocation.CountryCodeISO.Value = "RO";

    return MyObject;
}
```

Then in main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PathDetailsBLL train = new PathDetailsBLL();
    MyObject pdm = train.GetDataFromDatabase();
    Console.WriteLine(pdm.PathDetailsMessage.MessageTypeVersion);
    Console.WriteLine(pdm.PlannedJourneyLocation.CountryCodeISO.Value); 
}
```

Don`t forget to rename "MyObject" to your object ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUT params:

```
public void GetTwoObjects(out Object object1,out Object object2)
{
    object1 = new object();
    object2 = new object();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Object object1 = null;
    Object object2 = null;
    GetTwoObjects(out object1, out object2);
}
```